# Jquery: Replace string with values from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, replace

Say I have something like this:

```
var array = [cat,dog,fish];
var string = 'The cat and dog ate the fish.';
```

I want to clear all those values from a string

```
var result = string.replace(array,"");
```

The result would end up being: `The  and  ate the .`

Right now, `replace()` appears to only be replacing one value from the array. How can I make it so all/multiple values from the array are replaced in the string?

Thanks!

Comment: Smells like homework. Well your example is invalid, running the array line will throw errors. And have you ever use a `for` loop or `each()` and `new RegExp()`? Hint, try that.

Answer (score 12):

You either *create* a custom *regexp* or you loop over the string and replace manually.

```
array.forEach(function( word ) {
    string = string.replace( new RegExp( word, 'g' ), '' );
});
```

or

```
var regexp = new RegExp( array.join( '|' ), 'g' );

string = string.replace( regexp, '' );
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string.replace(new RegExp(array.join("|"), "g"), "");
```